# List of articles specific to some page

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and this question should be very easy for more experienced users.

I have few pages where I would like to display page content with additional list of wordpress posts specific for this page.

For example:

Page Products has some content that I insert on page and I would like to have list of product articles displayed on the same page.

At the moment i use index.php for displaying pages and I use the_content() method to display page content.

My question is how to display page content and below that list of articles specific for that page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get posts in template file? If you wanted to print latest posts try this in `page.php` or in your custom template. You can also get posts by **CategoryID**. [Try this For Getting posts by CatID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40839/how-to-get-all-posts-related-to-particular-category-name)

```
<?php
$lastposts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3
) );

if ( $lastposts ) {
    foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

Hope this Helps!!